# How to SWITCH to FF within Win7

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I use Windows 7 64-bit and Firefox 11.  I have a hotkey within Windows 7 to load Firefox with a single stroke (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) which works fine.

However, with my other programs (to which I have assigned a hotkey) striking that hotkey not only loads it, but also switches to it if it is already loaded. This does not happen with Firefox on my computer.

Is there a setting within Firefox to allow this to happen?

Comment: Is the app pinned to the task bar?

Comment: @Geoff - Yes the app is pinned to the task bar.